# Filling the model with sample images

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class Phrase(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,
                              default="",
                              null=False,                              
 upload_to=UploadTo(folder=UPLOAD_TO.VOCABULARY_IMG_FOLDER).save_path)
```

**Script**

```
sample_img_dir = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'doc', 'samples', 'img')
sample_images = os.listdir(sample_img_dir)
img = random.choice(sample_images)
f = open(os.path.join(sample_img_dir, img))
sample_img = File(f)

obj = Phrase(
        image=sample_img
    )
obj.save()
```

I have a model with an ImageField. I want to fill it with sample data. This is not  about testing. I just want to fill the database for development purposes. I saved some 50 jpg files and decided to add them programmatically.

I failed miserably. This code blows up with the exception:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open(os.path.join(sample_img_dir, img), "rb")
```

should do the trick. If not you can try to add the encoding standard like

```
f = open(os.path.join(sample_img_dir, img), "rb", encoding="utf-8")
```

But I'm not sure if this even works with bytes, it might only work for `"r"`.

You should give the file also a name:

```
sample_img = File(f, img)
```

If you already have the model created you can slo save the file afterwards with:

```
phrase = Phrase.objects.get(pk=1)
phrase.upload_to.save(img, content=sample_img))
```

#### small edit:

you can faster create a new entry with the following command:

```
phrase = Phrase.objects.create(
    image=sample_img
)
```